# Python PIL - Rotate an image around a point that isn't the center

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is it possible to rotate an image around a point that isn't the image center using PIL?

If not what could you folk recommend for me to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Similar problem here. Does PIL rotate an image about centre of image or the origin (which is the top left corner of image in my case)?

Answer (score 2):

By default, it rotates around the center of the image, to answer the commenter's question. Otherwise, you can specify coordinates, starting from the top left.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
resultIm = im.rotate(45, center=(25, 25))
```

See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate for documentation.